# Using LIKE operator for array of objects inside jsonb field in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-like, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

Is it possible to use LIKE operator for single key/value inside array of objects for jsonb field in PostgreSQL 9.4? For example I have:

```
 id |                  body                                                              
------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"products": [{"name": "qwe", "description": "asd"}, {"name": "zxc", "description": "vbn"}]}
```

I know, I can get a `product` with something like this:

```
select * from table where 'body'->'products' @> '[{"name": "qwe"}]'::jsonb
```

The question is: can I get this product if I don't know full name of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the `key` and `value` by using [**`jsonb_each()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) function:

```
WITH json_test(data) AS ( VALUES
  ('{"products": [{"name": "qwe", "description": "asd"}, {"name": "zxc", "description": "vbn"}]}'::JSONB)
)
SELECT doc.key,doc.value
FROM json_test jt,
  jsonb_array_elements(jt.data->'products') array_elements,
  jsonb_each(array_elements) doc
WHERE
  doc.key = 'name'
AND
  doc.value::TEXT LIKE '%w%';
```

Output will be the following:

```
 key  | value 
------+-------
 name | "qwe"
(1 row)
```