# Querying using like on JSONB field

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a field in a PostgreSQL database with a JSONB type in the format of `["tag1","tag2"]` and I am trying to implement a search that will provide results for a predictive dropdown (i.e. if a user types "t" and the column above exists both tags are returned.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I tried the query below but it is not working:

```
SELECT table.tags::JSONB from table where table.tags::TEXT like 't%';
```

Comment: What is "not working" about it? What is your expected result?

Comment: It is returning no results even though there are tags that should match the query.  I'm noticing the query is way off I'm trying to modify it based on the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596716/using-like-operator-for-array-of-objects-inside-jsonb-field-in-postgresql but because the jsonb structure is so different in the linked question I can't figure out how to adapt it to my structure

Comment: Take a look at `json_array_elements_text`. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do that is using *jsonb_array_elements_text()* function (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Example test:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    jsonb_array_elements_text($$["tag1","tag2","xtag1","ytag1"]$$::jsonb)
WHERE   value LIKE 't%';
 value
-------
 tag1
 tag2
(2 rows)
```

Since jsonb_array_elements_text() creates set of records and in your case there is no other condition than LIKE then using LATERAL (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) should help you out like this:

```
SELECT  T.tags
FROM    table T,
LATERAL jsonb_array_elements_text(T.tags) A
WHERE   A.value LIKE 't%';
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use WITH (a.k.a. CTE) query.

See more: [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html)

Comment: Thanks that worked perfect! It was difficult to find answers where the JSONB column was not in the structure of a more complex object instead of just an array